# Why isn't my LESS doing anything?

Tags: html, less

I am trying to use less to style a simple header, but for some reason, I can't get my LESS to do anything. Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I am running `WampServer` and technically the file i am using is **index.php** not **index.html**, but it is basically HTML (I am just using php to handle page requests)

**HTML Head:**

```
<head>
        <link rel="icon" type="favicon" href="/icon.ico"/>
        <title>Computer Immersion Inventory</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/css/header.less"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/css/footer.less"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/css/login.less"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/login.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/less/dist/less.js"></script>
</head>
```

**LESS Code:**

```
header {
   max-width:100%;
   height:50%;
   background: lighten(green, 45%);
   * {
        display: inline-block;
     }
}

.logo-box {
   width:30%;
   img {
      max-width:100%;
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you load the page?

Comment: Are the file paths correct? It seems to work here -> https://plnkr.co/edit/tfz2mfU3YPfoaQ1C9Yt7?p=preview

Comment: Your paths seem a bit weird, some have `../` and some don't.

Comment: @Steve if any of the files didn't exist, would that prevent the ones that do exist from loading?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure on how your compile is working, but should you not compile to a CSS file and have this included in header.

The browser will not render the .less files for you...you need to compile/process and convert first.

```
/css/header.less
```

should be

```
/css/header.css
```

Comment: No, it is not necessary to include the compiled CSS file. Client side compilation is possible using less.js. Please check the plunker in Josh's comment to the question.

Comment: @Neil Kearney how do I compile my less code? do i use less.js, or is there another software i need?

Comment: http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser, first load LESS JS, then load the LESS files..